# How to hide the top menu of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

How to hide the top menu of chrome?  `File/Edit/View/...`

[image: top menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to hide the whole menu bar:

1. Open *System Preferences*.
2. Click *General*
3. Under the *Appearance* section, check "Automatically hide & show the menu bar".
4. Close *System Preferences*; the menu bar on your computer should now automatically show when you mouse over it, and hide when you move your mouse cursor somewhere else.

PS. This applies to all applications, not just Chrome.

Comment: Is there any way to show right icons like the picture I just updated?

Comment: @DanielJyc Without modifying the application itself, no.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
Hidden dock + hidden menubar = so much more screen real estate